# Bind function to jQuery Dialog drag event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag

How can I run a function when a jQuery UI dialog is dragged?

I tried binding dialogdrag, draggable, drag, but none of these are working :(

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with what you currently have? AFAIK all the above should work fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#id").bind("dialogdragstart", function()
{
   // stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-drag)

Supply a callback function to handle the drag event as an init option.

```
    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
       drag: function(event, ui) { ... }
    });
```

Bind to the drag event by type: dialogdrag.

```
    $( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogdrag", function(event, ui) {
      ...
    });
```

If it's not working with above code, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "start" method option in jquery ui draggable

```
$("div").draggable({
    start: function(){ ... }
});
```